# QDomDocument fails to set content of an HTML document with <!doctype> tag

Tags: qt, dom, html-parsing, doctype, qtxml

When I use `QDomDocument` with HTML content, it fails to set content if there is a `<!doctype html>` at the beginning of the document. But actually why?!
for example consider the following snippet of code:

```
 QDomDocument doc;
 QString content = "<!doctype html><html><body><a href='bar'>foo</a></body></html>";
 qDebug() << doc.setContent(content,false,0,0);
 QDomElement docElem = doc.documentElement();
 QDomNode a = docElem.firstChild();
 qDebug() << doc.childNodes().size() << docElem.childNodes().size();
```

nothing but a list of `false`s are the output of this code!

Answer (score 7):

HTML is HTML and XML is XML. Consequently, `Qt XML` is not able to parse HTML code correctly. To parse HTML files, consider using the `Qt Webkit` module instead of the `Qt XML` module. To include it in your project, you just have to add `QT += webkit` in your project file.

To parse your HTML datas, you will have to do something like this :

```
QString content = "<html><body><a href='bar'>foo</a></body></html>";
QWebPage webPage;
QWebFrame * frame = webPage.mainFrame();
frame->setHtml(content);
QWebElement htmlElement = frame->documentElement();    // Equivalent of the QDomElement
```

For further informations, see the [Qt Webkit documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtwebkit.html) and the [QWebElement documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwebelement.html).

Comment: Thanks for your response. I think the Webkit is what I'm gonna use. but anyway, HTML is nothing but a kinda subset of xml, with predefined tag names! and I didn't except xml parser fail to parse HTML!

Answer (score 0):

Use the optional arguments to `setContent` to find out what the parsing error is. It could be something as simple as the case of "doctype".

Comment: I also tried that, but the `QStringList` of errors is still empty after calling `setContent()`!

Comment: Did you try DOCTYPE instead of doctype? BTW, what version of Qt are you using?