# How can I keep &ldquo; when I use QDomDocument to parse html data?

Tags: html, c++, qt

```
void test()
    {
        QDomDocument doc("doc");
        QByteArray data = "<div><p>Of course, &ldquo;Jason.&rdquo; My thoughts, exactly.</p></div>";

        QString sErrorMsg;
        int errLine, errCol;

        if (!doc.setContent(data, &sErrorMsg, &errLine, &errCol)) {
            qDebug() << sErrorMsg;
            qDebug() << errLine << ":" << errCol;
            return;
        }

        QDomNodeList pList = doc.elementsByTagName("p");
        for (int i = 0; i < pList.size(); i++)
        {
            QDomNode p = pList.at(i);
            while (!p.isNull()) {
                QDomElement e = p.toElement(); 
                if (!e.isNull()) {
                    QByteArray ba = e.text().toUtf8(); //Here, there is no left and right quota marks anymore.

                }
                p = p.nextSibling();
            }
        }

    }
```

I'm parsing a html phrase with `&ldquo;`and `&rdquo;`. The code runs to `QByteArray ba = e.text().toUtf8();` without the quota marks.

How do I keep them?

Comment: Are you sure it's not just your debug console that can't display those?

Comment: @rustyx, I saw every ba[i].

Comment: @rustyx, I did another test `QByteArray data = "<div><p>&ldquo;</p></div>"`. `e.toElement().text().size()` is 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I must admit that this is the first time that I used [QDomDocument](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdomdocument.html) although I already have some experience with XML in general and [libXml2](http://www.xmlsoft.org/) specifically.

First, I can confirm that [QDomElement::text()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdomelement.html#text) returns text without the typographical quotes encoded by entities.

I modified the MCVE of OP a bit and now, it should be obvious why this happens.

My `testQDomDocument.cc`:

```cpp
#include <QtXml>

static const char* toString(QDomNode::NodeType nodeType);

int main(int, char**)
{
  QByteArray text = "<div><p>Of course, &ldquo;Jason.&rdquo; My thoughts, exactly.</p></div>";
  // setup doc. DOM
  QDomDocument qDomDoc("doc");
  QString qErrorMsg; int errorLine = 0, errorCol = 0;
  if (!qDomDoc.setContent(text, &qErrorMsg, &errorLine, &errorCol)) {
    qDebug() << "Line:" << errorLine << "Col.:" << errorCol << qErrorMsg;
    return 1;
  }
  // inspect DOM
  QDomNodeList qListP = qDomDoc.elementsByTagName("p");
  const int nP = qListP.size();
  qDebug() << "Number of found <p> nodes:" << nP;
  for (int i = 0; i < nP; ++i) {
    const QDomNode qNodeP = qListP.at(i);
    qDebug() << "node <p> #" << i;
    qDebug() << "node.toElement().text(): " << qNodeP.toElement().text();
    for (QDomNode qNode = qNodeP.firstChild(); !qNode.isNull(); qNode = qNode.nextSibling()) {
      qDebug() << toString(qNode.nodeType());
      switch (qNode.nodeType()) {
        case QDomNode::TextNode:
#if 1 // IMHO, the correct way:
          qDebug() << qNode.toText().data();
#else // works as well:
          qDebug() << qNode.nodeValue();
#endif // 1
          break;
        case QDomNode::EntityReferenceNode:
          qDebug() << qNode.nodeName();
          break;
        default:; // rest of types left out to keep sample short
      }
    }
  }
  // done
  return 0;
}

const char* toString(QDomNode::NodeType nodeType)
{
  static const std::map<QDomNode::NodeType, const char*> mapNodeTypes {
    { QDomNode::ElementNode, "QDomNode::ElementNode" },
    { QDomNode::AttributeNode, "QDomNode::AttributeNode" },
    { QDomNode::TextNode, "QDomNode::TextNode" },
    { QDomNode::CDATASectionNode, "QDomNode::CDATASectionNode" },
    { QDomNode::EntityReferenceNode, "QDomNode::EntityReferenceNode" },
    { QDomNode::EntityNode, "QDomNode::EntityNode" },
    { QDomNode::ProcessingInstructionNode, "QDomNode::ProcessingInstructionNode" },
    { QDomNode::CommentNode, "QDomNode::CommentNode" },
    { QDomNode::DocumentNode, "QDomNode::DocumentNode" },
    { QDomNode::DocumentTypeNode, "QDomNode::DocumentTypeNode" },
    { QDomNode::DocumentFragmentNode, "QDomNode::DocumentFragmentNode" },
    { QDomNode::NotationNode, "QDomNode::NotationNode" },
    { QDomNode::BaseNode, "QDomNode::BaseNode" },
    { QDomNode::CharacterDataNode, "QDomNode::CharacterDataNode" }
  };
  const std::map<QDomNode::NodeType, const char*>::const_iterator iter
    = mapNodeTypes.find(nodeType);
  return iter != mapNodeTypes.end() ? iter->second : "<ERROR>";
}
```

The Qt project file – `testQDomDocument.pro`:

```
SOURCES = testQDomDocument.cc

QT += xml
```

Build and test:

```
$ qmake-qt5 testQDomDocument.pro

$ make && ./testQDomDocument 
g++ -c -fno-keep-inline-dllexport -D_GNU_SOURCE -pipe -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_XML_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I. -isystem /usr/include/qt5 -isystem /usr/include/qt5/QtGui -isystem /usr/include/qt5/QtXml -isystem /usr/include/qt5/QtCore -I. -I/usr/lib/qt5/mkspecs/cygwin-g++ -o testQDomDocument.o testQDomDocument.cc
g++  -o testQDomDocument.exe testQDomDocument.o   -lQt5Gui -lQt5Xml -lQt5Core -lGL -lpthread 
Number of found <p> nodes: 1
node <p> # 0
node.toElement().text():  "Of course, Jason. My thoughts, exactly."
QDomNode::TextNode
"Of course, "
QDomNode::EntityReferenceNode
"ldquo"
QDomNode::TextNode
"Jason."
QDomNode::EntityReferenceNode
"rdquo"
QDomNode::TextNode
" My thoughts, exactly."

$
```

To understand what happened it helps to know that the contents of `<p>` isn't stored in the `QDomNode` instance for `<p>` directly. Instead, the `QDomNode` instance for `<p>` (as well as any other element) has child nodes to store its contents, e.g. a [QDomText](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdomtext.html) instance to store a piece of text.

So, the `QDomElement::text()` is a convenience function which returns *only* the (collected) text but seems to ignore any other nodes.
In OPs sample, not all child nodes of the `QDomElement` for `<p>` are text nodes.

The entities (`&ldquo;`, `&rdquo;`) are stored as [QDomEntityReference](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdomentityreference.html) instances and obviously skipped in `QDomElement::text()`.

I must admit I was a bit surprised because (according to my experience in `libXml2`) I'm used to the fact that entities are resolved into text as well.

The paragraph in [QDomEntityReference](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdomentityreference.html):

> Moreover, the XML processor may completely expand references to entities while building the DOM tree, instead of providing QDomEntityReference objects.

supported my same expectation for `QDomDocument`.

However, the sample shows that this isn't true in this case.

---

Thinking twice, I realized that `&ldquo;` and `&rdquo;` are *not* predefined entities in XML.

This is the case in [HTML5 (and before)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references) but not in general XML.

The only predefined entities in XML are:

```
Name | Chr. | Codepoint   | Meaning
-----+------+-------------+-----------------
quot |  "   | U+0022 (34) | quotation mark
amp  |  &   | U+0026 (38) | ampersand
apos |  '   | U+0027 (39) | apostrophe
lt   |  <   | U+003C (60) | less-than sign
gt   |  >   | U+003E (62) | greater-than sign
```

So, for the replacement of HTML entities, something else is needed in `QDomDocument`.

Btw. while looking for a hint into this direction, I stumbled into:

[SO: QDomDocument fails to set content of an HTML document with  tag](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11918721/7478597)

---

I thought a while about how this can be fixed.

I wonder that I didn't think immediately on a very simple fix:
replacing the entities by [numeric character references](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numeric_character_reference).

```
HTML Entity | NCR
------------+----------
&ldquo;     | &#x201c;
&rdquo;     | &#x201d;
```

With a slight modification of the above sample:

```cpp
int main(int, char**)
{
  QByteArray text =
    "<div><p>Of course, &#x201c;Jason.&#x201d; My thoughts, exactly.</p></div>";
  // setup doc. DOM
  QDomDocument qDomDoc("doc");
  QString qErrorMsg; int errorLine = 0, errorCol = 0;
  if (!qDomDoc.setContent(text, &qErrorMsg, &errorLine, &errorCol)) {
    qDebug() << "Line:" << errorLine << "Col.:" << errorCol << qErrorMsg;
    return 1;
  }
  // inspect DOM
  QDomNodeList qListP = qDomDoc.elementsByTagName("p");
  const int nP = qListP.size();
  qDebug() << "Number of found <p> nodes:" << nP;
  for (int i = 0; i < nP; ++i) {
    const QDomNode qNodeP = qListP.at(i);
    qDebug() << "node <p> #" << i;
    qDebug() << "node.toElement().text(): " << qNodeP.toElement().text().toUtf8();
    for (QDomNode qNode = qNodeP.firstChild(); !qNode.isNull(); qNode = qNode.nextSibling()) {
      qDebug() << toString(qNode.nodeType());
      switch (qNode.nodeType()) {
        case QDomNode::TextNode:
          qDebug() << qNode.toText().data().toUtf8();
          break;
        case QDomNode::EntityReferenceNode:
          qDebug() << qNode.nodeName();
          break;
        default:; // rest of types left out to keep sample short
      }
    }
  }
  // done
  return 0;
}
```

I got the following output:

```
$ make && ./testQDomDocument
g++ -c -fno-keep-inline-dllexport -D_GNU_SOURCE -pipe -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_XML_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I. -isystem /usr/include/qt5 -isystem /usr/include/qt5/QtGui -isystem /usr/include/qt5/QtXml -isystem /usr/include/qt5/QtCore -I. -I/usr/lib/qt5/mkspecs/cygwin-g++ -o testQDomDocument.o testQDomDocument.cc
g++  -o testQDomDocument.exe testQDomDocument.o   -lQt5Gui -lQt5Xml -lQt5Core -lGL -lpthread 
Number of found <p> nodes: 1
node <p> # 0
node.toElement().text():  "Of course, \xE2\x80\x9CJason.\xE2\x80\x9D My thoughts, exactly."
QDomNode::TextNode
"Of course, \xE2\x80\x9CJason.\xE2\x80\x9D My thoughts, exactly."

$
```

Et voilà! Now, there is only one child node in `<p>` with the complete text including the quotes which are encoded as NCRs.

Though, the output of the quotes as `\xE2\x80\x9C` and `\xE2\x80\x9D` made me a bit uncertain. (Please, note that I added `.toUtf8()` to debug output because I got `?` and `?` before.)

A short check in [UTF-8 encoding table and Unicode characters](https://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=8220) convinced me that these UTF-8 byte sequences are correct.
But why the escaping?
Wrong `LANG` setting of my `bash`?

```
$ ./testQDomDocument 2>&1 | hexdump -C
00000000  4e 75 6d 62 65 72 20 6f  66 20 66 6f 75 6e 64 20  |Number of found |
00000010  3c 70 3e 20 6e 6f 64 65  73 3a 20 31 0a 6e 6f 64  |<p> nodes: 1.nod|
00000020  65 20 3c 70 3e 20 23 20  30 0a 6e 6f 64 65 2e 74  |e <p> # 0.node.t|
00000030  6f 45 6c 65 6d 65 6e 74  28 29 2e 74 65 78 74 28  |oElement().text(|
00000040  29 3a 20 20 22 4f 66 20  63 6f 75 72 73 65 2c 20  |):  "Of course, |
00000050  5c 78 45 32 5c 78 38 30  5c 78 39 43 4a 61 73 6f  |\xE2\x80\x9CJaso|
00000060  6e 2e 5c 78 45 32 5c 78  38 30 5c 78 39 44 20 4d  |n.\xE2\x80\x9D M|
00000070  79 20 74 68 6f 75 67 68  74 73 2c 20 65 78 61 63  |y thoughts, exac|
00000080  74 6c 79 2e 22 0a 51 44  6f 6d 4e 6f 64 65 3a 3a  |tly.".QDomNode::|
00000090  54 65 78 74 4e 6f 64 65  0a 22 4f 66 20 63 6f 75  |TextNode."Of cou|
000000a0  72 73 65 2c 20 5c 78 45  32 5c 78 38 30 5c 78 39  |rse, \xE2\x80\x9|
000000b0  43 4a 61 73 6f 6e 2e 5c  78 45 32 5c 78 38 30 5c  |CJason.\xE2\x80\|
000000c0  78 39 44 20 4d 79 20 74  68 6f 75 67 68 74 73 2c  |x9D My thoughts,|
000000d0  20 65 78 61 63 74 6c 79  2e 22 0a                 | exactly.".|
000000db

$
```

Aha. That rather seems to be caused by `qDebug()` which escapes all bytes with values of 128 and above.

Comment: What's a zealous answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
    QTextDocument text;
    text.setHtml("&lt;&gt;&quot;");
    qDebug() << text.toPlainText();
```

I found this way, at least I don't have to hardcode to replace every escaped html character.