# Qt Android: is there a way to initialise a std::map with an initialiser list?

Tags: android, c++, qt, android-ndk, initializer-list

I'm writing a cross-platform app in C++14 and Qt. In some header files I'm defining `const static std::map`s to hold relations between enums and strings or lists. On the desktop compiler the code compiles and works fine, on the mobile compiler I get a series of `no matching constructor for initialization of 'const std::map<...>'` errors. Initializer lists for `std::vector`s seem to be accepted. The code is as follows:

```
static const std::map<enum, std::string> ENUM_TO_STRING = { { VALUE_ENUM, "value" } };
```

Which seems to be fine. I've read about using `APPLIB = gnulib_static` but it was a fix for Android Studio and doesn't make sense for Qt Creator. Runtime initialisation would defeat the purpose of having static constant maps so I'd rather avoid it, plus there are a lot of maps I would have to refill this way.

Do I have to use a different syntax for maps initializer lists? Is this feature even supported? If not, is there a way to provide it?

I'm using the Android ndk version r19 (possibly?), Qt Creator 4.8.1, Qt 5.12.0.

Comment: If you add `using namespace std::string_literals;` and then change `{ { VALUE_ENUM, "value" } }` to `{ { VALUE_ENUM, "value"s } }`, does it compile?

Comment: This is independent of Qt and Qt Creator and should only depend on the NDK (and thus compiler) used.

Comment: It does. Turns out I didn't include the string header. Probably std::string was included in map or vector and I didn't need to explicitly include it. After including it it wasn't even necessary to append "s"s to the string literals. Care to explain why / give a proper answer to be accepted?

Comment: @phagio Never rely on transient includes in cross-platform code (or *ever*, actually).

Comment: FYI: In my recent answer to [How can I keep &ldquo; when I use QDomDocument to parse html data?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59502604/7478597) I did something similar (`const char* toString(QDomNode::NodeType nodeType);`) but I used `const char*` for the texts. Actually, I don't see any need to copy constant literals into a `std::string` as they shouldn't never change in this specific case.